# Unable to Calculate Position within Owner-Draw Text

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2012 to create a Windows Forms application that can place the caret at the current position within a owner-drawn string. However, I've been unable to find a way to accurately calculate that position.

[I've done this successfully before in C++](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/mfc-hex-editor-control). I've tried numerous methods in C# but have not yet been able to position the caret accurately. Originally, I tried using .NET classes to determine the correct position, but then I tried accessing the Windows API directly. In some cases, I came close, but after some time I still cannot place the caret accurately.

I've created a small test program and posted key parts below. I've also posted the entire project [here](http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/TestFont.zip).

The exact font used is not important to me; however, my application assumes a mono-spaced font. Any help is appreciated.

**Form1.cs**
This is my main form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string TestString;
    private int AveCharWidth;
    private int Position;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestString = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
        AveCharWidth = GetFontWidth();
        Position = 0;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.CreateCaret(Handle, (IntPtr)0, 2, (int)Font.Height);
        Windows.ShowCaret(Handle);
        UpdateCaretPosition();
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected void UpdateCaretPosition()
    {
        Windows.SetCaretPos(Padding.Left + (Position * AveCharWidth), Padding.Top);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.HideCaret(Handle);
        Windows.DestroyCaret();
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TestString, Font, SystemBrushes.WindowText,
            new PointF(Padding.Left, Padding.Top));
    }

    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Left:
                return true;
        }
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                Position = Math.Max(Position - 1, 0);
                UpdateCaretPosition();
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                Position = Math.Min(Position + 1, TestString.Length);
                UpdateCaretPosition();
                break;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected int GetFontWidth()
    {
        int AverageCharWidth = 0;

        using (var graphics = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.TEXTMETRIC tm;
                var hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
                IntPtr hFont = this.Font.ToHfont();
                IntPtr hOldFont = Windows.SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
                var a = Windows.GetTextMetrics(hdc, out tm);
                var b = Windows.SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
                var c = Windows.DeleteObject(hFont);
                AverageCharWidth = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                graphics.ReleaseHdc();
            }
        }
        return AverageCharWidth;
    }
}
```

**Windows.cs**
Here are my Windows API declarations.

```
public static class Windows
{
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct TEXTMETRIC
    {
        public int tmHeight;
        public int tmAscent;
        public int tmDescent;
        public int tmInternalLeading;
        public int tmExternalLeading;
        public int tmAveCharWidth;
        public int tmMaxCharWidth;
        public int tmWeight;
        public int tmOverhang;
        public int tmDigitizedAspectX;
        public int tmDigitizedAspectY;
        public short tmFirstChar;
        public short tmLastChar;
        public short tmDefaultChar;
        public short tmBreakChar;
        public byte tmItalic;
        public byte tmUnderlined;
        public byte tmStruckOut;
        public byte tmPitchAndFamily;
        public byte tmCharSet;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCaretPos(int x, int y);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DestroyCaret();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool GetTextMetrics(IntPtr hdc, out TEXTMETRIC lptm);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);
    [DllImport("GDI32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
}
```

**Edit**

The code I've posted has an issue that makes it even more inaccurate. This is a result of trying many different approaches, some more accurate than this. What I'm looking for is a fix that makes it "fully accurate", as it is in my [MFC Hex Editor Control in C++](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/mfc-hex-editor-control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried out your `GetFontWidth()`, and the width of a character returned was **7**.
I then tried out `TextRenderer.MearureText` on varying lengths of text and had values ranging from **14** through to **7.14** for text of length 1 to 50 respectively with an average character width of **7.62988874736612**.

Here is the code I used:

```
var text = "";
var sizes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<double>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    text += (i % 10).ToString();
    var ts = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, this.Font);
    sizes.Add((ts.Width * 1.0) / text.Length);

}
sizes.Add(sizes.Average());
Clipboard.SetText(string.Join("\r\n",sizes));
```

Not satisfied with the results of my little 'experiment', I decided to see how the text was rendered onto the form. Below is a screen capture of the form (magnified 8x).

[image: Magnified font measurement]

On close inspection, I observed that

1. There was an amount of separation between the characters. This made the length of a block of text (`1234567890`) is **74** pixels long.
2. There is some space (3px) in front of the text being drawn even though the left padding is 0.

#### What does this mean to you?

- If you use your code to calculate the width of a font character, you fail to account for the separating space between two characters.
- Using the `TextRenderer.DrawText` can give you varying character widths rendering it quite uselesss.

#### What are your remaining options?

- The best way I can see out of this is to hard-code the placement of your text. That way you know the position of each character and can accurately place the cursor at any desired location.
  Needless to say, this is likely going to call for a lot of code.
- Your second option is to run tests like I did to find the length of a block of text and then divide by the length of the block to find the average character width.
  The problem with this is that your code is not likely to scale properly. For example, changing the size of the font or the user's screen DPI can cause a lot of trouble for the program.

#### Other things I observed

- The space inserted in-front of the text is equivalent to the width of the caret (*2px* in my case) plus 1px (Total of 3px).
- Hard-coding the width of each character to 7.4 works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and work with some of these ideas. As I indicated, this works perfectly when I've done it in C++ so I'm not sure why it needs to be so hard. The issues seems to be the print method which is messing with the spacing.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It appears the text rendering is messing up the spacing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer` to in order to draw the string as well as to calculate its metrics. Various method overloads for both operations exist

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "abc", font, point, Color.Black);
Size measure = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, "1234567890", font);
```

I have made good experiences with `TextRenderer` and its accuracy.

---

**UPDATE**

I determined the font size like this in one of my applications and it worked perfectly

```
const TextFormatFlags textFormatFlags =
    TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix | 
    TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping;

fontSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.g, "_", font, 
                                    new Size(short.MaxValue, short.MaxValue),
                                    textFormatFlags);
height = fontSize.Height;
width = fontSize.Width;
```

Make sure to use the same format flags for both drawing and measuring.

<sub>(This way of determining the font size of cause works only for monospaced fonts.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this. For some reason, my caret does not always end up at exactly the right position. I suspect it might not be related to the way I measure the font but rather something about the way I'm interpreting it.

Comment: Maybe the text format flags `TextFormatFlags.NoPadding` and  `TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix` will help.

Comment: How did you obtain `this.g`?

Comment: Either way, if I create a graphics object and run this code, and then use the result to position my caret, it's off considerably.

Comment: It is the `Graphics` object. The code shown above is from a helper class that I called "FontDescriptor". `g` is just a member in this class. Usually you would get it from the argument `e.Graphics` of the `OnPaint` method or the `Paint` event handler.

Comment: Yes, I understood it was a `Graphics` object. I was just curious how you were obtaining it since I've tried about a half dozen ways while testing this. But, again, it just isn't producing accurate results for me. Again, perhaps it's related to how I interpret it somehow.

Comment: Maybe you should use the "real" graphics object from the `OnPaint` method, as this one has device specific settings (things like pixels per inch of your graphics adapter).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that (although ultimately, this will need to be computed outside of the Paint event). Over several days, I've tried everything I could think of. That's why I posted a link to my entire project. I'm obviously missing something more fundamental.

Comment: Actually I am using the `CreateGraphics` method of my control where the rendering happens. `CreateGraphics` is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

Comment: "Where the rendering happens" should be in your Paint event, in which case there should be no reason to create one because one is already created for you (with the proper clipping rectangle). Yes, I know `CreateGraphics` is inherited from the `Control` class. In either case, I appreciate your input but none of this helps me. Just hoping someone who understands this a little better than I will take a look at my project.

Comment: You can call `CreateGraphics` it in the load event of a form for instance, instead of recalculating the font size each time in the `Paint` event. I called it in the constructor of a UserControl after `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: Is there some scroll bar involved? In that case you would have to correct the screen position of the carret by the scroll offset.

Comment: There is no scrollbar on the simple test project I created, which you can see for yourself.